# Multiple for loops calling same list of random variables not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to create functions that call on a random list generated 'random_plan'. Essentially for each value in the list (4) I need to create a for loop, but for each loop that calls the random list:

e.g.

```
for x in random_plan(): 
    if x[0] == 1:
       goto(x_cord, y_cord)
```

it generates a new list of values in the shell. So instead of the loops each taking a value from the same random list, 4 random lists are being created. 
Is their a way to ensure all loops for calling the same list created? or any easier way around this.

Comment: Only one list is being created here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one list is being created, and then you are looping through the result of it.  Check out this example:

```
import random

def random_plan():
    print('Random plan is being run!')
    x = random.sample(range(1, 100), 4)
    print(x)
    return x

for i in random_plan():
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
Random plan is being run!
[87, 20, 60, 96]
87
20
60
96
```

You are only calling the function once.